# How to format Python Ordered-Dictionary in a tabular format

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tabular, ordereddictionary

I am trying to format a Python Ordered Dictionary in a tabular format as shown below. How can I format the ordered dictionary data in the below format?

```
OrderedDict([
  ('parent_ mods', OrderedDict([('pk_release', None)
                                ('product_value', None),
                                ('bar_activity', 'create'),
                                ('host_model', False),
                                ('active', True),
                                ('model_facet', False),
                                ('is_active', True)])),
  ('product_name', OrderedDict([('pk_release', None),
                                ('product_value', None),
                                ('bar_activity', 'create'),
                                ('host_model', False),
                                ('active', True),
                                ('model_facet', False),
                                ('is_active', True)]))
])
```

I have tried the code below to separate the keys and data values, but only two dict keys are showing up in the output.

```
import json

dblock = json.loads(relc_json,
                    object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
bkeys = list(dblock.keys())
print(bkeys)
```

**Output**

```
['parent_mods', 'product_name']
```

How can I format the `OrderedDict` data in the format below?

```
|parent_mods|

|pk_release|product_value|bar_activity|host_model|active|model_facet|is_active|
|None|None|create|False|True|Fasle|True|

|product_name|

|pk_release|product_value|bar_activity|host_model|active|model_facet|is_active|
|None|None|create|False|True|Fasle|True|
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there *are* only two keys in the root dict, so I'm not sure what other output you'd hope for.

For this output, there's probably I library somewhere, but it doesn't seem too hard in terms of formatting.

```
import json

dblock = json.loads(relc_json,
                    object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

for key, value in dblock.items():
    print(f'|{key}|')
    print()
    joined_subkeys = '|'.join(value.keys())
    joined_subvalues = '|'.join(value.values())
    print(f'|{joined_subkeys}|')
    print(f'|{joined_subvalues}|')
    print()
```